# how to compare columns in two different .csv file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
A=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/amulya/Desktop/graves lab/main_now.csv", index_col=False, header=None)
DATA1=pd.DataFrame(A)
DATA1[0]
B=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/amulya/Desktop/graves lab/words.csv", index_col=False, header=None) 
DATA2=pd.DataFrame(B)
DATA2[0]
for xrow in range (1,len(DATA1)):  
for yrow in range (1,len(DATA2)):
    if DATA2== DATA1:
    print(DATA1[3])
```

"In column 1 of DATA1 file there is numbers from 1-3000, and in column 1 of DATA2 there 465 random numbers . I want to search these numbers in DATA1 file and print rest of the columns"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isin` to find if the value in `col1` of Data2 is a value in `col1` of Data1 and then slice Data1 by that boolean DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                    'col2': [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 101, 6, 9, 4]})
```

We have the two `DataFrames` `df1` and `df2`. You can select the first column of the first dataframe by its column name by either `df['col1']` or equivalently `df.col1`

```
df1.col
#0    1
#1    2
#2    3
#3    4
#4    5
```

The condition you want is whether the value in df1.col1 appears in the first column of df2. This is accomplished with the `isin` function. The syntax reads as you expect, it looks for 'whether df1.col1 is in df2.col1' and returns a True/False dataframe.

```
df1.col1.isin(df2.col1)
#0     True
#1    False
#2    False
#3     True
#4    False
#5     True
```

When you then slice `df1` by this true false dataframe, it returns only the rows that were `TRUE`, in this case the indices 0,3,5 and 8. It will return all columns, as you are only slicing the dataframe by rows.

```
df1[df1.col1.isin(df2.col1)]
#   col1  col2
#0     1     1
#3     4     7
#5     6    11
#8     9    17
```

Comment: that's great!! but both my files are .csv files with DATA1 file having 103 colums and 2999 rows. And DATA2 have 1 column and 465 rows. So with the above solution we have to mention all the column names?

Comment: i am beginner in python..so m not clear how to go about t.could you please elaborate on the solution?

Comment: No not at all!  `df1.col1.isin(df2.col1)` returns a single column `DataFrame` that is just `True` or `False` indicating whether that value was found anywhere in the first column of DATA2. When you then slice the first dataframe by `df`[]` it return all columns, but only the rows where the condition was true

Comment: You will replace `df1` by `DATA1` and `df2` by `DATA2`. And the only other thing you need to specify are the column names for the first columns in your dataframes. so `df1.col1` should be replaced by `DATA1.whatever_your_column_is_named` and the same for `df2`

Comment: Worked!! thanks for the help. Also wanted to know how to put output  back to .csv file??

Comment: [To CSV](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) has all of the information. it allows you to write any dataframe to a csv.